# Is there a way to get the version from the 'package.json' file in Node.js code?

Tags: node.js, npm, version, versioning, package.json

Is there a way to get the version set in the *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file in a Node.js application? I would want something like this

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen port
console.log "Express server listening on port %d in %s mode %s", app.address().port, app.settings.env, app.VERSION
```

Comment: Is it more important to get the version of Node or the version declared in package.json?

If the form, this will give you the running version: `console.log(process.version)`

Comment: Yes, you can easily get the version from the package.json file in Node.js code. Here's how you can do it:
const version= require('./package.json').version;

Answer (score 1281, accepted):

I found that the following code fragment worked best for me. Since it uses `require` to load the `package.json`, it works regardless of the current working directory.

```js
var pjson = require('./package.json');
console.log(pjson.version);
```

**A warning, courtesy of [@Pathogen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616987/pathogen):**

> Doing this with Browserify has security implications.
> Be careful not to expose your `package.json` to the client, as it means that all your dependency version numbers, build and test commands and more are sent to the client.
> If you're building server and client in the same project, you expose your server-side version numbers too.
> Such specific data can be used by an attacker to better fit the attack on your server.

Comment: if you keep getting burned by trying to grab this from different places (as I was), you can do `require('root-require')('package.json').version`

Comment: @mikermcneil Rather than using `root-require`, you can also just delete the `require.cache` between requests since you know you don't want the cached version.  Alternatively, it sounds like `__dirname` may have helped in your situation too.

Comment: Not working for my script with shebang installed globally. `Error: Cannot find module 'package.json'`.

Comment: huh, I would hope that process global var would have some info about the package.json file that was used to start the process.

Comment: shorter - require('./package').version

Comment: Using a method to upgrade the version automatically as part of your build, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059991/update-package-json-version-automatically, should also be a part of this answer.

Comment: Warning! Doing this with browserify has security implications: package.json in your bundle means that all your dependency version numbers, build and test commands and more are sent to the client. If you're building server and client in the same project, you expose your serverside version numbers too.

Comment: How to get version of main package? _require('../../package.json')_ not work?

Comment: Note that if you are using browserify, it probably means you are "packaging" your webapp in some way (whether that's just minifying, transpiling with babel, etc. etc.).  If so, you can use the same method listed here, but don't do it in your application code -- do it in a custom browserify transform step.  Perhaps your main app configuration can have a line like `Config.version = 'VERSION';`, your transform step just has to replace the string 'VERSION' with the version from package.json.  Then your packaged app has access to the version without worrying about `package.json`.

Comment: @Pathogen [genversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/genversion) solves the issue on client side. It's a tool that reads the version from package.json and generates an importable module from it. Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer.

Comment: `var pjson = require('package.json')` potentially will expose your whole `package.json`, which you most likely don't want to.  
  
Better option is answer by Julien Christin, which is using: `process.env.npm_package_version`

Comment: There's better answers further down the page that don't have horrible security implications.

Comment: Could setting `pjson = null` after using the version attenuate the security issue?

Comment: No. If you reference the file it needs to include it in the build. It has nothing to do with in-memory.

Comment: easy, and simple to use

Comment: Warning! it will also create the following message [CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies) which should be avoided in typescripts project cause it "results in larger bundle sizes - Angular".

Comment: Gonna vouch for [genversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/genversion) here. As a TS user, it's real easy to add in a build step. Plus, I don't have to worry one bit that some dependent package will build my code in some way that exposes package.json. I'd much rather have the version number copied out (automagically) and exported to the rest of the code that way.

Answer (score 726):

If your application is launched with `npm start`, you can simply use:

```
process.env.npm_package_version
```

See [package.json vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars) for more details.

Comment: this is probably the best answer since most of the information in package.json is attached to the process runtime variable

Comment: Yeap, I'm agree. This should be the right answer, using the process variable you don't need to open and read again the package.json file.

Comment: And outside of node (e.g., shell scripts executed via `npm run …`) the version will be in the environment variable `$npm_package_version`.

Comment: When called from scripts of another package, this incorrectly reports the version of the _calling_ package and not the _called_ package.

Comment: It works within an [electron](http://electron.atom.io) app started with `npm start`, but not within a built electron app: for that, you can find it in [`app.getVersion`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetversion).

Comment: This does NOT return the version inside a NW.js (node-webkit) application.

Comment: @gbmhunter This worked in electron ran from the command line, but didn't work in the packaged version built with electron-builder :-(

Comment: FYI re: electron, `app.getVersion()` works in built electron apps, but (at least in my dev env), it _only_ works in built apps--dev env returns electron's version, so in renderer it'd be something like `process.env.npm_package_version || require('electron').remote.app.getVersion()`

Comment: @jjrv it's not *incorrect* per se, as it is the version in the only package.json that was parsed by npm. The dependencies are loaded by node require and don't pass through npm. Furthermore, `process` is the node global and overwriting this property when entering a dependency would mean the value in the parent package and all other dependencies would change as well.

Comment: @Brandon Actually I use `require('electron').app.getVersion()`. What's that `remote` you wrote?

Comment: This looks like the safest way to get the version of your application.

Comment: This does not seem to work with `yarn`--you may get an old version from the last time you ran the application with `npm`.

Comment: If these variables are `undefined`, depending on your authoring environment you may need to forward these environment variables from the entry point run by Node.js to the part of your code that aims to access it. In my case, I was using Webpack and needed to add a [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to expose these `package.json` vars from the config file during the build process to the bundled code which was not ran by Node.js.

Comment: Looks like it works with yarn on my end as well

Comment: I wanted app version for an express server /status page.  This did perfect.  FWIW even though the prefix is 'npm' these work with yarn start as well

Comment: This is the best way !

Comment: As of npm v7, only a few values are available using `process.env.npm_package_*`, despite the docs still saying otherwise. See [this issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2609) and [npm RFC21](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md).

Comment: This worked good for me!

Comment: The critical bit is that it not `npm start` but any `npm run` command. If you have `"foo": "node ./index.js"` in your `package.json` then `npm run foo` **will** have the environment variables, but critically running `node ./index.js` on its own **will not** have any npm environment variables.

Answer (score 285):

Using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) modules, you can do the following:

```
import {version} from './package.json';
```

Comment: I thought these were not supported in node: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53

Comment: No es6 modules are not yet directly supported but commonly used anyway, enabled using Babel

Comment: It hides the other configurations like dependencies? I'm thinking to show the version in the home page of a Meteor application.

Comment: @Sornii no, the entire package.json will be in the client. I used webpack's definePlugin to pass only selected info from node environment to browser.

Comment: I couldn't get the ES6 destructuring to work with jspm's json plugin

Comment: Module not found: You attempted to import /package.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Comment: Any security implication like as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855054/540144 ?

Comment: Yes, same security issues. The entire package.json will be included in the client bundle.

Comment: On Node 14.17.6 I got `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for /my/project/package.json`

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy (I know this is old) if you're using a "raw" Node program, like a command-line tool, Node currently does not know how to import JSON files via ES6 imports. The answer and other comments are based on work that some build tool does. When there's no build step, and you're basically doing `node mycode.js`, there does not seem to be a way to get at `package.json` short of reading it, which is itself problematic because the code would have to *find* it.

Comment: This works great when building with Vite, and adding the version number statically with `define` in `vite.config.js/ts`. Only the version number will be added to the bundle, nothing else. Just make sure you `JSON.stringify(version)` so it will be included as a string.

Comment: And here I was, struggling to import the `package.json` file in my ES6 ESM code! You are a lifesaver.

Comment: [See this other question I asked today, of course forgetting that I had found this previously.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76781496/node-program-module-reading-its-own-package-json-is-that-possible/76782867#76782867) There is a really reliable and easy way to do it, it turns out, from ES6 modules even.

Answer (score 159):

Or in plain old shell:

```
node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').version);"
```

This can be shortened to

```
node -p "require('./package.json').version"
```

Comment: That's not within the nodeJS app itself though, as requested.

Comment: I used this but it stopped working for Node 16 telling me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'` - any ideas?

Answer (score 108):

There are two ways of retrieving the version:

1. Requiring `package.json` and getting the version:

```
const { version } = require('./package.json');
```

2. Using the environment variables:

```
const version = process.env.npm_package_version;
```

Please don't use `JSON.parse`, `fs.readFile`, `fs.readFileSync` and don't use another `npm modules` it's not necessary for this question.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Then `npm_*` environment values are only available if your script was started by NPM, e.g. `npm start`. If you are doing `node app.js` or similar, they will not be present.

Comment: @Nate So it is better to use version from `package.json`?

Comment: You can also add a script `"start": "node app.js"` to your package.json and start your app using `npm start`—that'll give your the npm env vars

Comment: This worked for me in typescript, just needed to add `"resolveJsonModule": true` to my config

Answer (score 83):

Here is how to read the version out of package.json:

```
fs = require('fs')
json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8'))
version = json.version
```

Of other answers, probably the cleanest is:

```
const { version } = require('./package.json');
```

Here's the [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) version:

```
import {version} from './package.json';
```

Comment: I've seen this a bunch, and I do like it - do you/anyone know the considerations that `require() introduces? (for instance, does `require()`not support utf8 reading? as your snippet may suggest)

Comment: `require()` caches the file, which in this case should not make a difference.

Comment: @jlee is there a reason people commonly do `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8'))` instead of `delete require.cache[require.resolve('package.json')]; require('package.json')` when they want to reload?

Comment: const { version } = require('./package.json');

Comment: Any way using 'import' from ES6?

Comment: please dont use this LMAO. this small task doesn't require the heavy process of reading a file from file system.

Answer (score 81):

For those who look for a safe **client-side** solution that also works on server-side, there is [genversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/genversion). It is a command-line tool that reads the version from the nearest package.json and generates an importable CommonJS module file that exports the version. Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer.

```
$ genversion lib/version.js
```

I acknowledge the client-side safety was not OP's primary intention, but as discussed in answers by [Mark Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855054/638546) and [aug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46287598/638546), it is highly relevant and also the reason I found this Q&A.

Comment: This is THE answer, and it needs more votes to get above the deeply problematic answer on top right now.

Comment: Some people might be alarmed by the fact that this is a command line tool. Do not worry! The tool's readme describes how to (easily) integrate the call on build into package.json, so that you can forget about the existence of the tool and always will have the most recent version number.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thanks @Akseli.

Comment: YES!!!  This is the right answer.  Nobody should be shipping their package.json file with their app.

Comment: @EricJorgensen Brilliantly put, thank you :) May I quote your comment on the genversion repository README.md?

Comment: @Akseli - sure!

Comment: @Akseli - PS:  I've been using genversion with my service and it has been working flawlessly.  Thank you for creating this tool

Answer (score 39):

NPM one liner:

From [npm v7.20.0](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.20.0):

`npm pkg get version`

Prior to npm v7.20.0:

`npm -s run env echo '$npm_package_version'`

Note the output is slightly different between these two methods: the former outputs the version number surrounded by quotes (i.e. `"1.0.0"`), the latter without (i.e. `1.0.0`).

One solution to remove the quotes in Unix is using `xargs`

```
npm pkg get version | xargs
```

Comment: Note that this only works in npm. If you're running something from node_modules/.bin with "#! /usr/bin/env node" you can't implement --version using this trick

Answer (score 27):

There is another way of fetching certain information from your *package.json* file, namely using the [pkginfo](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pkginfo) module.

Usage of this module is very simple. You can get all package variables using:

```
require('pkginfo')(module);
```

Or only certain details (`version` in this case):

```
require('pkginfo')(module, 'version');
```

And your package variables will be set to `module.exports` (so the version number will be accessible via `module.exports.version`).

You could use the following code snippet:

```
require('pkginfo')(module, 'version');
console.log "Express server listening on port %d in %s mode %s", app.address().port, app.settings.env, module.exports.version
```

---

This module has very nice feature. It can be used in any file in your project (e.g., in subfolders) and it will automatically fetch information from your *package.json* file. So you do not have to worry where your *package.json* file is.

Comment: what is `module` here?

Comment: @chovy, `module` is not this specific example variable; it is a variable  representing the current module in node.js. You can read more about node.js modules here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object

Comment: I'm trying to get the version of other modules required by my module... and I'm having a hard time figuring out if pkginfo makes this possible.

Comment: I tried using `pkginfo` with ES6 modules, but nothing worked. I can't see how you can translate `require('pkginfo')(module)` into `import` syntax.

Comment: There is now https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-pkg which does something similar but is much more up-to-date and well maintained

Answer (score 24):

**Option 1**

Best practice is to version from package.json using npm environment variables.

```
process.env.npm_package_version
```

more information on: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config.html

This will work only when you start your service using NPM command.

> Quick Info: you can read any values in pacakge.json  using process.env.npm_package_[keyname]

**Option 2**

Setting version in environment variable using https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv as `.env` file and reading it as `process.env.version`

Comment: Nice and clean. Thank you!

Comment: it's `undefined` for me.

Comment: @Boris - You are trying option 1 or 2?

Comment: Option 1 on Node 14, using ES modules. Maybe it's because I'm running my code with `node index.js`. How do I run a [`"bin": "my-bin.js"`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) through npm?

Answer (score 18):

we can read the version or other keys from `package.json` in two ways

1- using `require` and import the key required e.g:

```
const version = require('./package.json')
```

2 - using [package_vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars) as mentioned in doc

```
process.env.npm_package_version
```

Comment: These are set by npm but not by the node binary, which means it won't work for the bin directory (my main use for needing this sort of information)

Comment: Version 1 worked for me, but slightly different:
`import {version} from '../../package'`

Answer (score 16):

Just adding an answer because I came to this question to see the best way to include the version from package.json in my web application.

I know this question is targetted for Node.js however, if you are using Webpack to bundle your app just a reminder the recommended way is to use the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to declare a global version in the config and reference that. So you could do in your `webpack.config.json`

```
const pkg = require('../../package.json');

...

plugins : [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      AppVersion: JSON.stringify(pkg.version),
...
```

And then `AppVersion` is now a global that is available for you to use. Also make sure in your [`.eslintrc` you ignore this via the globals prop](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals)

Answer (score 14):

A safe option is to add an npm script that generates a separate version file:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "yarn version:output && blitz build",
    "version:output": "echo 'export const Version = { version: \"'$npm_package_version.$(date +%s)'\" }' > version.js"
  }
```

This outputs `version.js` with the contents:

```js
export const Version = { version: "1.0.1.1622225484" }
```

Comment: what is `blitz build` ?

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for `module (package.json: "type": "module")` (ES6 import) support, e.g. coming from refactoring commonJS, you should (at the time of writing) do either:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';

const pkg = JSON.parse(await readFile(new URL('./package.json', import.meta.url)));

console.log(pkg.version)
```

or, run the node process with `node --experimental-json-modules index.js` to do:

```
import pkg from './package.json'
console.log(pkg.version)
```

You will however get a warning, until json modules will become generally available.

If you get Syntax or (top level) async errors, you are likely in a an older node version. Update to at least node@14.

Comment: This is the best answer. There's no better way than to do it yourself; No 3-P deps, and one line. Alternative(s): **1.** Since Node v18 you can pass `--resolveJsonModule` at invocation to load modules with JSON extensions (no longer experimental). **2.** Without any flags you can `await` top level - and also dynamically import: `const VERSION = ( await import( 'package.json' ) ).version`.  Though, for simplicity: `const version = JSON.parse( ( await fs.readFile( path.join( './', 'package.json' ), { encoding: 'utf8' } ) ) ).version;`. Done (provide encoding - otherwise a Buffer is returned.)

Answer (score 11):

You can use ES6 to import package.json to retrieve version number and output the version on console.

```
import {name as app_name, version as app_version}  from './path/to/package.json';

console.log(`App ---- ${app_name}\nVersion ---- ${app_version}`);
```

Comment: This works as long as you set "resolveJsonModule" to "true" in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 9):

To determine the package version in node code, you can use the following:

1. `const version = require('./package.json').version;` for < ES6 versions
2. `import {version} from './package.json';` for ES6 version
3. `const version = process.env.npm_package_version;`
   if application has been started using `npm start`, all npm_* environment variables become available.
4. You can use following npm packages as well - root-require, pkginfo, project-version.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't use the require resolve...

```
const packageJson = path.dirname(require.resolve('package-name')) + '/package.json';
const { version } = require(packageJson);
console.log('version', version)
```

With this approach work for all sub paths :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using `create-react-app` and I don't have `process.env.npm_package_version` available when executing my React-app.

I did not want to reference `package.json` in my client-code (because of exposing dangerous info to client, like package-versions), neither I wanted to install an another dependency (genversion).

I found out that I can reference `version` within `package.json`, by using `$npm_package_version` in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "my_build_script": "REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-scripts start"
}
```

Now the version is always following the one in `package.json`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [project-version](https://github.com/simonepri/project-version) package.

```
$ npm install --save project-version
```

Then

```
const version = require('project-version');

console.log(version);
//=>  '1.0.0'
```

It uses `process.env.npm_package_version` but fallback on the version written in the `package.json` in case the env var is missing for some reason.

Comment: For example if the js file was started not from npm?

Comment: Why would you want to add yet another package if it can be done so simply as @ÁngelBlanco suggests?!

Comment: I wrote this in 2017, and I don't think the LTS version of node we had back then supported the ES6 syntax used by @ÁngelBlanco.

Comment: The `project-version` package uses https://github.com/sindresorhus/read-pkg - this package is much better maintained than `project-version`, so I would use `read-pkg` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I know this isn't the intent of the OP, but I just had to do this, so hope it helps the next person.

If you're using [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools) for your [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Deploy_an_artefact_from_CI) process, you can get it this way!

```
version:
  image: node:7-alpine
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/service/
  working_dir: /usr/src/service/
  command: ash -c "node -p \"require('./package.json').version.replace('\n', '')\""
```

For the image, you can use any Node.js image. I use [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux), because it is the smallest.

Answer (score 5):

The leanest way I found:

```js
const { version } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'))
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to get version of the target package.

```
import { version } from 'TARGET_PACKAGE/package.json';
```

**Example:**

```
import { version } from 'react/package.json';
```

Answer (score 5):

I've actually been through most of the solutions here and they either did not work on both Windows and Linux/OSX, or didn't work at all, or relied on Unix shell tools like grep/awk/sed.

The accepted answer works technically, but it sucks your whole package.json into your build and that's **a Bad Thing** that only the desperate should use, temporarily to get unblocked, and in general should be avoided, at least for production code. One alternative is to use that method only to write the version to a single constant that can be used as a source file for the build, instead of the whole file.

So for anyone else looking for a cross-platform solution (not reliant on Unix shell commands) and local (without external dependencies):

Since it can be assumed that Node.js is installed, and it's already cross-platform for this, I just created a `make_version.js` file (or `make_version.cjs` in more recent environments) with:

```
const PACKAGE_VERSION = require("./package.json").version;
console.log(`export const PACKAGE_VERSION = "${PACKAGE_VERSION}";`);
console.error("package.json version:", PACKAGE_VERSION);
```

and added a `version` command to `package.json`:

```
scripts: {
    "version": "node make_version.js > src/version.js",
```

or

```
scripts: {
    "version": "node make_version.cjs > src/version.js",
```

(for a CommonJS file) and then added:

```
    "prebuild": "npm run version",
    "prestart": "npm run version",
```

and it creates a new `src/versions.js` on every `start` or `build`.  Of course this can be easily tuned in the `version` script to be a different location, or in the `make_version.js` file to output different syntax and constant name, etc.

Note also that the pnpm package manager does not automatically run "pre" scripts, so you might need to adjust it for two commands if using that PM.

Comment: Note that with recent module support updates in Node and some ecosystems, in some environments you would actually *need* to name the above make_version.cjs (extension) rather than .js for this to continue to work correctly.  I ran into this with Solid-Start and I suspect others will with Next, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am using gitlab ci and want to automatically use the different versions to tag my docker images and push them. Now their default docker image does not include node so my version to do this in shell only is this

scripts/getCurrentVersion.sh

```sh
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
cat $BASEDIR/../package.json | grep '"version"' | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g; s/,//g'
```

Now what this does is

1. Print your package json
2. Search for the lines with "version"
3. Take only the first result
4. Replace " and ,

Please not that i have my scripts in a subfolder with the according name in my repository. So if you don't change $BASEDIR/../package.json to $BASEDIR/package.json

Or if you want to be able to get major, minor and patch version I use this

scripts/getCurrentVersion.sh

```sh
VERSION_TYPE=$1
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
VERSION=$(cat $BASEDIR/../package.json | grep '"version"' | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g; s/,//g')

if [ $VERSION_TYPE = "major" ]; then
  echo $(echo $VERSION | awk -F "." '{print $1}' )
elif [ $VERSION_TYPE = "minor" ]; then
  echo $(echo $VERSION | awk -F "." '{print $1"."$2}' )
else
  echo $VERSION
fi
```

this way if your version was 1.2.3. Your output would look like this

```sh
$ > sh ./getCurrentVersion.sh major
1

$> sh ./getCurrentVersion.sh minor
1.2

$> sh ./getCurrentVersion.sh
1.2.3
```

Now the only thing you will have to make sure is that your package version will be the first time in package.json that key is used otherwise you'll end up with the wrong version

Answer (score 2):

I do this with [`findup-sync`](https://github.com/cowboy/node-findup-sync):

```
var findup = require('findup-sync');
var packagejson = require(findup('package.json'));
console.log(packagejson.version); // => '0.0.1'
```

Comment: findup starts with cwd, so in most cases it would just get the top level `package.json`, similar to `process.env.npm_package_version` besides not requiring it to be started via npm. So trying to get your library version would actually get the caller's version.
A simple require('./package.json') would avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

I made a useful code to get the parent module's package.json

```
function loadParentPackageJson() {
    if (!module.parent || !module.parent.filename) return null
    let dir = path.dirname(module.parent.filename)
    let maxDepth = 5
    let packageJson = null
    while (maxDepth > 0) {
        const packageJsonPath = `${dir}/package.json`
        const exists = existsSync(packageJsonPath)
        if (exists) {
            packageJson = require(packageJsonPath)
            break
        }
        dir = path.resolve(dir, '../')
        maxDepth--
    }
    return packageJson
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If using rollup, the `rollup-plugin-replace` plugin can be used to add the version without exposing package.json to the client.

```js
// rollup.config.js

import pkg from './package.json';
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonJS from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';

export default {
  plugins: [
    replace({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      'MY_PACKAGE_JSON_VERSION': pkg.version, // will replace 'MY_PACKAGE_JSON_VERSION' with package.json version throughout source code
    }),
  ]
};
```

Then, in the source code, anywhere where you want to have the package.json version, you would use the string 'MY_PACKAGE_JSON_VERSION'.

```
// src/index.js
export const packageVersion = 'MY_PACKAGE_JSON_VERSION' // replaced with actual version number in rollup.config.js
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const { version } = require("./package.json");
console.log(version);

const v = require("./package.json").version;
console.log(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Import your `package.json` file into your `server.js` or `app.js` and then access package.json properties into server file.

```
var package = require('./package.json');
```

package variable contains all the data in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

```
const packageJson = require('./package.json'); // Adjust the path if needed

const appVersion = packageJson.version;

console.log(`The version specified in package.json is: ${appVersion}`);
```

This code assumes that your package.json file is in the root directory of your Node.js application. If it's located in a different directory, adjust the require path accordingly.

This will log the version specified in your package.json to the console. You can use the appVersion variable in your application as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple method that works in all environments. My app is written in TypeScript, but the changes to JavaScript are minor.

Add this script to `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
  "generate:buildinfo": "echo 'export default { version: \"'$npm_package_version'\", date: new Date('$(date +%s)'000) }' > ./src/buildInfo.ts",
  "prebuild": "npm run generate:buildinfo"
}
```

In some other TypeScript file:

```js
import buildInfo from 'buildInfo.js'
console.log(buildInfo.version, buildInfo.date)
```

Comment: Can the person who voted this down please leave a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can easily get the version from the package.json file in Node.js code. Here's how you can do it:

```
const version= require('./package.json').version;
```

Comment: Duplicate of other existing answers

Answer (score -2):

Used to version web-components like this:

```
const { version } = require('../package.json')

class Widget extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
  }

  public connectedCallback(): void {
    this.renderWidget()
  }

  public renderWidget = (): void => {
    this.shadowRoot?.appendChild(this.setPageTemplate())
    this.setAttribute('version', version)
  }
}
```