# update package.json version automatically

Tags: git, node.js, npm, githooks

Before I do a small release and tag it, I'd like to update the package.json to reflect the new version of the program.

Is there a way to edit the file `package.json` automatically?

Would using a `git pre-release hook` help?

Comment: Why don't ou make a shell script which edit package.json, commits and then tag it?

Comment: yeah so the pre-release hook would invoke that script right?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214586/git-hook-update-package-json-version/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796533/how-can-i-place-my-meteor-apps-version-number-in-the-ui

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`npm version` is probably the correct answer. Just to give an alternative I recommend [grunt-bump](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump). It is maintained by one of the guys from angular.js.

Usage:

```
grunt bump
>> Version bumped to 0.0.2

grunt bump:patch
>> Version bumped to 0.0.3

grunt bump:minor
>> Version bumped to 0.1.0

grunt bump
>> Version bumped to 0.1.1

grunt bump:major
>> Version bumped to 1.0.0
```

If you're using grunt anyway it might be the simplest solution.

Comment: And if you're using [gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com/): [gulp-bump](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-bump) :)

Comment: I coded Vik for this, which bumps npm, Bower, etc... in one fell swoop: https://github.com/Wildhoney/Vik

Comment: why use external libraries when npm has this functionality built in?

Comment: What's the benefit of using these over `npm version`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd like to know why some people downvoted this answer.

Comment: Is there a way to use `npm version` without forcing it to tag in this format `v\d.\d.\d`?

Comment: @ConAntonakos Yes. Try something like `npm --no-git-tag-version version patch`.

Comment: Yarn has similar functionality built-in. See Eric Kim's answer.

Comment: @JohannPhilippStrathausen Probably people downvoted because even though it mentions `npm version` (which is the correct answer to the question) it proposes `grunt`, which is not the correct answer (I could elaborate for a very long time why it's not the correct answer but that would be probably something more than the characters I am allowed to add here)

Comment: @JohannPhilippStrathausen you can see why I think this anwer is not the best in my comment below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54788216/4229159) hope it helps, and remember, the fact that you can do something with other commands doesn't mean they are the best

Answer (score 259):

**Right answer**

To do so, just `npm version patch` =)

**My old answer**

There is no `pre-release` hook originally in `git`. At least, `man githooks` does not show it.

If you're using `git-extra` (https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras), for instance, you can use a `pre-release` hook which is implemented by it, as you can see at https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-release. It is needed only a `.git/hook/pre-release.sh` executable file which edits your `package.json` file. Committing, pushing and tagging will be done by the `git release` command.

If you're not using any extension for `git`, you can write a shell script (I'll name it `git-release.sh`) and than you can alias it to `git release` with something like:

`git config --global alias.release '!sh path/to/pre-release.sh $1'`

You can, than, use `git release 0.4` which will execute `path/to/pre-release.sh 0.4`. Your script can edit `package.json`, create the tag and push it to the server.

Comment: could you share a code snippet of what would the script look like? :D

Comment: Check this link out https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-release

Comment: i actually use visionmedia's git-extra repo. But ``git release`` does not update the package.json accordingly ... https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/issues/150 :D

Comment: So, just create `.git/hooks/pre-release.sh` containing: `echo -e "{\n\"version\": "$1"\n}" > package.json` and try using `git release $version`

Comment: as Commented [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/issues/150#issuecomment-10070145) ``npm version patch`` or ``npm version 0.3.1``  will solve it! Could you update your answer accordingly? ty!!

Comment: Yes please update answer, the solution is `npm version patch` -- thanks

Comment: Is there a way to do this without commit to git? I just want to update the package version

Comment: @qodeninja does `npm version` use git?

Comment: When I stage my changes and run `npm version patch -m 'My cnages message'`,

npm gives me `Git working directory not clean.` error.

Which forces me to make two commits every time. one for my changes and one for version increment

Answer (score 106):

This is what I normally do with my projects:

```
npm version patch
git add *;
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push
npm publish
```

The first line, `npm version patch`, will increase the patch version by 1 (x.x.1 to x.x.2) in `package.json`. Then you add all files -- including `package.json` which at that point has been modified.
Then, the usual `git commit` and `git push`, and finally `npm publish` to publish the module.

I hope this makes sense...

Merc.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `npm version patch` does the commit itself; however, to push the tag to github, I think you also need to `git push --tags`.

Comment: @ChrisV is correct -- `npm version patch` bumps the version number *and immediately commits the change*

Comment: @DanEsparza This might be a setting thing. `npm version patch` does not commit anything for me.

Comment: @Mordred Hmmm ... possibly.  I don't see anything in the [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) docs about that, but could it be that you don't have git in your path or something?

Comment: @DanEsparza git is definitely in the path as I commit from the exact same folder I run `npm version`.

Comment: If i want to use npm verision patch from bamboo (CI) then how would you determine whether to increment, the major or minor versions?

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't the selected answer.

Comment: I would like to amend previous commit instead of creating new.

Answer (score 46):

To give a more up-to-date approach.

#### `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "eslint": "eslint index.js",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "npm run eslint",
    "preversion": "npm run test",
    "version": "",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags && npm publish"
  }
```

Then you run it:

```sh
npm version minor --force -m "Some message to commit"
```

Which will:

1. ... run tests ...
2. change your `package.json` to a next minor version (e.g: 1.8.1 to 1.9.0)
3. push your changes
4. create a new git tag release and
5. publish your npm package.

`--force` is to show who is the boss! Jokes aside see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8620

Comment: You can also add a script like `"deploy-minor": "npm version minor --force -m \"version %s\""` so all you need to remember is `npm run deploy-minor` :)

Answer (score 43):

As an addition to `npm version` you can use the `--no-git-tag-version` flag if you want a version bump but no tag or a new commit:

```
npm --no-git-tag-version version patch
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

Answer (score 38):

If you are using yarn you can use

```
yarn version --patch
```

This will increment `package.json` version by patch `(0.0.x)`, commit, and tag it with format `v0.0.0`

Likewise you can bump minor or major version by using `--minor` or `--major`

When pushing to git ensure you also push the tags with `--follow-tags`

```
git push --follow-tags
```

You can also create a script for it

```
    "release-it": "yarn version --patch && git push --follow-tags"
```

Simply run it by typing `yarn release-it`

Comment: yarn version patch not wtih (--).  [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version)

Comment: The best and clearest answer is "yarn version --patch" thanks to @Eric Kim

Answer (score 16):

I am using [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and [git-branch-is](https://github.com/kevinoid/git-branch-is):

As of husky v1+:

```
// package.json
{
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "post-merge": "(git-branch-is master && npm version minor || 
  (git-branch-is dev && npm --no-git-tag-version version patch)",
    }
  }
}
```

Prior to husky V1:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postmerge": "(git-branch-is master && npm version minor || 
  (git-branch-is dev && npm --no-git-tag-version version patch)",
  ...
},
```

Read more about [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)

**Webpack or Vue.js**

If you are using webpack or Vue.js, you can display this in the UI using [Auto inject version - Webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-auto-inject-version)

*NUXT*

In `nuxt.config.js`:

```
var WebpackAutoInject = require('webpack-auto-inject-version');

module.exports = {
  build: {
    plugins: [
      new WebpackAutoInject({
        // options
        // example:
        components: {
          InjectAsComment: false
        },
      }),
    ]
  },
}
```

Inside your `template` for example in the footer:

```
<p> All rights reserved © 2018 [v[AIV]{version}[/AIV]]</p>
```

Comment: i like this husky option the best, although i don't think it works as is anymore.  i don't think 'postmerge' exists, "pre-push" is probably the best option.  and the 'git-branch-is' results don't really work since they error out and basically crash the whole post (since it's checking both master and dev, it'll error out on one of them)

Comment: @Phil You can still use `postmerge`, but it is now `post-merge` inside the `husky: {hooks:{}}` config. What issue do you have with `git-branch-is`?

Comment: it would just error out for me instead of running.  No worries though, i've ended up going with this option : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-Versioning-Task

Comment: @Phil thanks for following up. I just tried with updated version and I have no errors, perhaps something is wrong with your post-merge command itself.

Answer (score 14):

First, you need to understand the rules for upgrading the versioning number. You can read more about the [semantic version](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-semantic-versioning/) here.

Each version will have x.y.z version where it defines for different purpose as shown below.

1. x - major, up this when you have major changes and it is huge
   discrepancy of changes occurred.
2. y - minor, up this when you have
   new functionality or enhancement occurred.
3. z - patch, up this when
   you have bugs fixed or revert changes on earlier version.

To run the scripts, you can define it in your package.json.

```
"script": {
    "buildmajor": "npm version major && ng build --prod",
    "buildminor": "npm version minor && ng build --prod",
    "buildpatch": "npm version patch && ng build --prod"
}
```

In your terminal, you just need to npm run accordingly to your needs like

```
npm run buildpatch
```

If run it in git repo, the default git-tag-version is true and if you do not wish to do so, you can add below command into your scripts:

```
--no-git-tag-version
```

for eg: `"npm --no-git-tag-version version major && ng build --prod"`

Answer (score 13):

**I want to add some clarity to the answers this question got.**

Even thought there are some answers here that are tackling properly the problem and providing a solution, they are not the correct ones. The correct answer to this question is to use `npm version`

> Is there a way to edit the file package.json automatically?

Yes, what you can do to make this happen is to run the `npm version` command when needed, you can read more about it [here npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version.html), but the base usage would be `npm version patch` and it would add the 3rd digit order on your `package.json` version (1.0.**X**)

> Would using a git pre-release hook help?

You could configure to run the `npm version` command on the pre-release hook, as you need, but that depends if that is what you need or not in your CD/CI pipe, but without the `npm version` command a `git pre-release` hook can't do anything "easily" with the `package.json`

**The reason why `npm version` is the correct answer is the following:**

1. If the user is using a folder structure in which he has a `package.json` he is using `npm` if he is using `npm` he has access to the `npm scripts`.
2. If he has access to `npm scripts` he has access to the `npm version` command.
3. Using this command he doesn't need to install anything more in his computer or CD/CI pipe which on the long term will reduce the maintainability effort for the project, and will help with the setup

The other answers in which other tools are proposed are incorrect.

`gulp-bump` works but requires another extra package which could create issues in the long term (point 3 of my answer)

`grunt-bump` works but requires another extra package which could create issues in the long term (point 3 of my answer)

Comment: This should be the best answer in this case.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `version-select` package:

```sh
npm i -D version-select
```

```json
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "version-select": "version-select"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "version-select": "^1.0.13"
    }
}
```

[image]

[Read more](https://www.npmjs.com/package/version-select)

Comment: I like this approach as it is easy to implement. I struggled to get it to work with a husky pre-commit hook though. Seems to throw error `TypeError: this.stream.setRawMode is not a function`. I'm guessing `version-select` doesn't like being run inside another process or something?

Comment: @Stretch0 I'm not sure about the husky pre-commit hook but my `version-select` implementation is straight forward. You can find it here - https://github.com/dm-grinko/version-select/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 6):

Just in case if you want to do this using an npm package `semver` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver)

```
let fs = require('fs');
let semver = require('semver');

if (fs.existsSync('./package.json')) {
    var package = require('./package.json');
    let currentVersion = package.version;
    let type = process.argv[2];
    if (!['major', 'minor', 'patch'].includes(type)) {
        type = 'patch';
    }

    let newVersion = semver.inc(package.version, type);
    package.version = newVersion;
    fs.writeFileSync('./package.json', JSON.stringify(package, null, 2));

    console.log('Version updated', currentVersion, '=>', newVersion);
}
```

`package.json` should look like,

```
{
  "name": "versioning",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Update version in package.json using npm script",
  "main": "version.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "version": "node version.js"
  },
  "author": "Bhadresh Arya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "semver": "^7.3.2"
  }
}
```

just pass `major`, `minor`, `patch` argument with `npm run version`. Default will be `patch`.

example:
`npm run version` or `npm run verison patch` or `npm run verison minor` or `npm run version major`

[Git Repo](https://github.com/bhadresharya/stationary/tree/master/fs-semver)

Answer (score 3):

With [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky):

```json
{
  "name": "demo-project",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch && git add ."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in this case, you have to change your package.json file every time because it's not gonna be "patch" always.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko What do you mean by "not gonna be patch" ???!!! I'm using it for my project, works perfectly, for every commit, and I don't have to care about it after initial setup

Comment: the "patch" change is only one option. There are "minor" and "major" changes as well

Comment: I think it's enough for the answer in this case

Comment: Calling `git add .` in a pre-commit hook is rather dangerous.  You can mistakenly add files you weren't intending to commit and not even know it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [tool](https://github.com/GetchaDEAGLE/eagle-versioner) that can accomplish automatic semantic versioning based on the tags in commit messages, known as change types. This closely follows the Angular Commit Message Convention along with the Semantic Versioning Specification.

You could use this tool to automatically change the version in the package.json using the npm CLI (this is described [here](https://github.com/GetchaDEAGLE/eagle-versioner#versioning-automation)).

In addition, it can create a changelog from these commits and also has a menu (with a spell checker for commit messages) for creating commits based on the change type. I highly recommend checking it out and reading to docs to see everything that can be accomplished with it.

I wrote the tool because I couldn't find anything that suited my needs for my CICD Pipeline to automate semantic versioning. I'd rather focus on what the actual changes are than what the version should be and that's where my tool saves the day.

For more information on the rationale for the tool, please [see this](https://danieleagle.com/2020/01/introducing-eagle-versioner/).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I hope this approach can help someone in case you want to automatically update two package.json in a different location in order to use the same version.

First of all, add these lines to your main pakcage.json scripts section:

```
"new-version": "npm version --git-tag-version=false",
"version": "echo 'starting postversion script'",
"postversion": "LAST_VERSION=$(npm pkg get version | sed 's/\"//g') && echo $LAST_VERSION && cd projects/ngx-timeline && sed -i.bak \"s/\\\"version\\\": \\\"[0-9]\\.[0-9]\\.[0-9]\\\"/\\\"version\\\": \\\"$LAST_VERSION\\\"/g\" package.json && rm package.json.bak && git commit -am \"Release $LAST_VERSION\" && git tag v$LAST_VERSION"
```

Then running for instance npm run new-version minor,

1. the first script will run the npm version with the minor and the option to avoid the tag
2. the version script will run the command you need after the default ones ( in my case just an echo )
3. In the postversion script with a sed I can override the version in my child package.json, amend the commit (the version script created already one commit by default) and then create a tag.

Answer (score 0):

My build and publish scripts run in a docker image that has no access to git and so I wanted some approach that doesn't modify my repository but is able to publish auto-incremented version. So I added this to prepublish script:

```
npm view `sed -nr 's/"name": "([^"]+).*/\1/p' package.json` version | awk -F'.' '{ cmd = "npm version v" $1 "." $2 "." $3+1 " --force --no-git-tag-version"; system(cmd)}'
```

What it does:

1. reads package name with sed
2. asks for latest published version with npm view version
3. calls npm version --force --no-git-tag-version with version taken from (2) and increased by one

There are ways to improve it, but at least it works and it is universal.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing this solution (adding it to `package.json`) scripts. Yarn has very similar functionality.

```
"postversion": "git add package.json && git commit -m $npm_package_version && git tag $npm_package_version HEAD && git push --tags"
```

It updates version field, creates a new commit with `package.json` in it, commit's with the version name, tags it and pushed to branch.

Then, you can just run `npm version patch` | `npm version minor` | `npm version major` to create a versioned commit with tag in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/versi

All you need is to run `versi` a moment before you publish, and the CLI tool updates your patch. (can be done as a `prepack` or a `prepublishOnly` hook)

This relays on the contract that:

- patches are arbitrary and moving forward continuously and automatically.
- developers should own `major` and `minor` and use them to communicate breaking changes added features respectively

Therefore

- `package.json` is checked in with a zero patch
- the `versi` updates the patch after consulting the target registry to the next available patch within the major/minor pair.
- no commits are involved. (you could place a tag as a part of your CI if you wish..., I prefer the opposite -  automatically add the commit-sha to `package.json::ci.commit` together with `ci.date` etc. but that's not a part of `versi`)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that package. Although I implemented it with previous customers of mine, I never promoted it.

Answer (score -1):

Please check my [NodeAutoVersionPush](https://github.com/Sherbeeny/NodeAutoVersionPush) macro script.
It's a macro using Visual Studio Code API to auto set the new version then do commit and push with a keyboard shortcut.

The new version is based on current date and total commits.
But you can easily tweak the code to your preference or for any other language.