# Git hook update package json version

Tags: github, githooks, github-for-windows

In our project we often forget to update version numbers in `Package.json` file. Ours is  a AngularJS project.  In our package JSON file we are specifying the below two version information

```
"version": "1.0.7",
"devVersion": "1.0.4"
```

**Before Merging a branch to develop** I want a automated script to update these above two version numbers.  I am thinking Git Hooks will help me.

Where can i find the hooks, I am able to see the hooks in my local repo under `.git` folder.  I am confused which hook to use. Searching on Google suggests I have to create hooks on server.

Where can i find them and can i update the above both keys (version and devVersion) ?

Pls suggest the location and hook to use, this will solve a lot of problem.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059991/update-package-json-version-automatically/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796533/how-can-i-place-my-meteor-apps-version-number-in-the-ui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two kinds of hooks (both present in any .git/hooks folder): server and client hooks.
They are listed in "[Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)"

A merge is a local operation, so if you wanted to automate any process during a merge, you would need a client hook, like a `post-commit` hook (meaning executed just *after* creating a merge commit).
If you need to update that file *before* a merge, you can try a `pre-commit` hook, and [check if a merge is in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30781568/6309) (if not, your `pre-commit` hook would do nothing since you want to update the versions only before a merge).

You can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25801605/6309) an example of a [post-commit hook](https://gist.github.com/parhelium/cbba266a8da5ac102993) which generates a `version.json` file.
If is written in node, but you can write a hook ni any scripting language you want.

Answer (score 11):

I am using [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and [git-branch-is](https://github.com/kevinoid/git-branch-is):

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postmerge": "(git-branch-is master && npm version minor || 
  (git-branch-is dev && npm --no-git-tag-version version patch)",
  ...
},
```

Read more about [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)

**Webpack or Vue.js**

If you are using webpack or Vue.js, you can display this in the UI using [Auto inject version - Webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-auto-inject-version)

*NUXT*

In `nuxt.config.js`:

```
var WebpackAutoInject = require('webpack-auto-inject-version');

module.exports = {
  build: {
    plugins: [
      new WebpackAutoInject({
        // options
        // example:
        components: {
          InjectAsComment: false
        },
      }),
    ]
  },
}
```

Inside your `template` for example in the footer:

```
<p> All rights reserved © 2018 [v[AIV]{version}[/AIV]]</p>
```

Comment: Interesting implementation, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 5):

With [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky), it's extremely simple:

```json
{
  "name": "demo-project",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch && git add ."
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I put `git add .` in the end because after we update package version, we need to stage it

Comment: In what file am I supposed to add this?

Comment: Seems that it's even more simple without Husky, because you only need (part of) the 6th line