# How to Automate version number in package.json with Jenkins

Tags: json, node.js, jenkins, sed, npm

Here is my **package.json** looks like:

`{
  "name": "Myproject",`
  `"version": "0.4.13",`

> **Note**:Here `4` is not the minor version.`0013` is minor

`"dependencies": {`
      `"lodash": "^4.0.0",`
    `"vinyl-fs": "2.2.1"`
  `},`
  `"repository": {},`
  `"devDependencies": {`
  `.........`
   `......`

How can I automate versioning of **package.json** using Jenkins build.

Required format should be:
**0.4.13-$BUILD_NUMBER**
So far I try to do it using **sed** command:

> sed -i "s/version: .*/version: 0.4.13-$BUILD_NUMBER/" package.json

But it's not updating version number in package.json file.
Also used

> npm version  0.4.13-$BUILD_NUMBER

**FYI:The generated build artifact should look like 0.0013-1.war**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using grunt, you could use the recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059991/update-package-json-version-automatically).

Alternatively, there's a built in function in npm that does this for you. Run `npm version`, [docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version).

Comment: Thank you @Dandy.I already gone through those.But the problem with `npm version` is it's not generating the version number as I expected.The format I'm looking for is `0.0013-1.war`

Comment: There's also [`yarn version`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version/) for anyone using yarn

Comment: Please check my [NodeAutoVersionPush][1] macro.
It's a script using Visual Studio Code API to auto set the new version then do commit and push with a keyboard shortcut.

The new version is based on current date and total commits.
But you can easily tweak the code to your preference or for any other language.


  [1]: https://github.com/Sherbeeny/NodeAutoVersionPush