# package.json - is it possible to use version as a variable in script

Tags: node.js

Every time I compress my project, I need to manually sync `version` with the generated file name like `CCCC007.tgz`
In my package.json, `compress-files` script like below:

```
{
  "name": "MyBuild",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./src",
    "start": "node src/",
    "compress-files": "tar --exclude='./node_modules' --exclude='./myBuild.pem' --exclude='./config/local.json' -zcvf ~/CCCC007.tgz . ",
  },
}
```

I am wondering whether I can make the `version` as variable and use it in the script `compress-files` with something like:

```
  "name": "MyBuild",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./src",
    "start": "node src/",
    "compress-files": "tar --exclude='./node_modules' --exclude='./myBuild.pem' --exclude='./config/local.json' -zcvf ~/CCCC${this.version}.tgz . ",
  },
```

Comment: This might help you **"Automating versioning and publication"**

https://itnext.io/how-to-automate-versioning-and-publication-of-an-npm-package-233e8757a526

Comment: @Nishant S Vispute `You’ve read all of your member-only stories this month.`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your comment is that msg you see on the link or is it a question

Comment: @Nishant S Vispute I cannot view the post in your link because I am not a member

Comment: neither am i a member on that site but somehow it does shows me the article anyways nevermind that link here is a link from StackOverflow for the same 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059991/update-package-json-version-automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to another object in JSON, and certainly not inside a value.

From the `/` direction, it looks like you're on linux. You can probaly do something like this:

```
"get-version": "node -e \"console.log(require('./package.json').version)\"",
"compress-files": "tar [...] `npm run get-version`",
```

That being said, there are tools to releases and versioning that should make life easier. You could give [Release-It](https://github.com/release-it/release-it) a try. But...if a package.json script with `tar` is all you need, don't let anyone tell you that you should be doing it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use this variables inside the package.json:

${npm_package_name}
${npm_package_version}

[Readed from this post](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2020/12/10/dotnet-project-builds-with-npm/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access package.json variables inside `scripts` section:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "inst": "code --install-extension ${npm_package_name}-${npm_package_version}.vsix",
    "unist": "code --uninstall-extension ${npm_package_name}-${npm_package_version}.vsix"
  },
```

Also you can access them as environment variables via `process.env`:

```js
http.createServer(...).listen(process.env.npm_package_config_port);
```

> The package.json fields are tacked onto the npm_package_ prefix. So, for instance, if you had {"name":"foo", "version":"1.2.5"} in your package.json file, then your package scripts would have the npm_package_name environment variable set to "foo", and the npm_package_version set to "1.2.5". You can access these variables in your code with process.env.npm_package_name and process.env.npm_package_version, and so on for other fields.

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for using package.json values in scripts is: (you need to escape in the string "...")

> %npm_package_name%

> %npm_package_version%

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "ng serve -o --ssl --project \"%npm_package_name%\""
}
```

here have another example (by:
Hadar Dashty): https://medium.com/@hadards/change-default-ng-serve-proxy-in-net7-project-with-angular-launch-998b1cdcaea2