Correct Syntax for Using sed Command in GitLab CI
I'm currently working on a GitLab CI/CD pipeline and I'm trying to use the sed command to dynamically update the contents of a file while the pipeline is running. My goal is to replace a placeholder version in a json file with a dynamic value that changes based on the pipeline execution context. I wrote a command in the .gitlab-ci.yml file, but I don't know if my syntax is correct or if there is a better way.
My questions are:
Is the syntax of my sed command correct for use in a GitLab CI pipeline?
Is there a more efficient or recommended way to perform text replacement in files within a GitLab CI pipeline?
build:
  image: node:alpine
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    VARIABLE: changed
  before_script:
    - [commands]
    - [commands]
    - [commands]
    - |
      sed -i 's/"version": "[^"]*"/"version": "'"$VARIABLE"'"/' app.json
  script:
    - cat app.json

This commands work on the runner :
$ sed -i 's/"version": "[^"]*"/"version": "'"$variable"'"/' app.json
$ cat app.json
{
    "something": {
      "version": "changed"
    }
}


s the syntax of my sed command correct for use in a GitLab CI pipeline? Did you try it? Does it work? Is there a more efficient Do you care about efficiency? Is sed not efficient enough? It shoudl execute in milliseconds, no? or recommended way The recommended way to parse JSON files is to use a JSON parser, like jq or python -c import json, not sed. But anyway, it looks like "node". Node guys have npm version patch, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059991/update-package-json-version-automatically . Python guys have bumpversion for example.

I tried this and it worked.
I was able to update tags in the Helm values file
 script:
    - docker build -t "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME" .
    - docker tag "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME" "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BUILD_NUMBER"
    - docker push "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BUILD_NUMBER"
    - git clone $HELM_REPO_URL 
    - cd helm-chart-repo
    - |
      sed -i 's/tag: "[^"]*"/tag: "'"$BUILD_NUMBER"'"/' values.yaml

