# Read a custom field from package.json synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want users of my module to be able to customize its behavior by specifying a custom field in package.json but can't figure out how to read it synchronously. If I wanted to read `someField` out of the package.json of an app or module using my module, how would I do that?

Comment: Please, see my answer to a similar question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22339262/1860357

Answer (score 3):

```
var pjson = require('./package.json');
console.log(pjson.yourcustomfield);
```

adopted from another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855054/7602).

Comment: You can omit the `.json` filename extension if you want so it can be .json, .js, .coffee, etc.

Comment: No, that reads it from my own package. If you imagine my package is called `guest`, and it is being used by an app called `host`, I want to access the field defined in host's package.json, form the code running in my guest module.

Comment: Looks like resolving that path gets the right behavior. Anyone see a problem with this? `require(require('path').resolve('./package.json')).someField`

Comment: @bclinkinbeard it looks good, though I would worry about rogue guests that want to ruin my file system.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fs.readFileSync` node.js method of the fs module to read the file synchronously.