# Share constant from node.js sever to js files in frontend app

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, package.json

I have a node.js server and a package.json file. In that file I set some variables. For exemple "version" : 3.0. I can access those variables very easily in the node.js server. ([Is there a way to get version from package.json in nodejs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code))

```
var pjson = require('./package.json');
console.log(pjson.version);`
```

But how can I pass it to my js app working on the frontend? Can I create a constant.js file that is created went I start the server (only ones).

I do not want to pass the variable as an argument every time I render a page.

I use the ejs to render my pages.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `I do not want to pass the variable as an argument every time I render a page` -- why not?

Comment: It will not change from the start of the server to the end. Ans it's less code to write :)

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: yes I am. The js for the frontend is rendered by the static module of express

Answer (score 1):

You could set a cookie in the initial response.

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["version=3.0"])
```

Comment: Can I access it in js app on the frontend after ? i'm not sure I know how :(

Comment: yes, just use `document.cookie` in client-side JS code -- this gives you all your cookies in a string (separated by semicolons); just parse from there (using `split`). MDN has some good docs on document.cookie: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie

Comment: I guess you could set a cookie on login or some entry point. but there is hardly any processing with a variable in your rendering `res.render('/hom', {version:currentVersion})`. This better because you dont need to worry about users altering cookies client side, its reset on every render.

Comment: @Rob I see want you mean. I thought about it. I didn't want to do it this way because the render recalculates the page each time, and I don't need it. I only need it to be calculated ones.