# "node -r package.json" - how to access inside object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Following [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code) other answer I am trying to retrieve values from `package.json`.

With "preload" feature I hope to do it like this:

```
echo 'console.log(???.name)' | node -r package.json
```

But the `???` bit is missing. What could it be in this case?
Thanks.

Comment: For the time being I have resorted to `echo 'console.log(require("./package.json").name)' | node`, but this question still stands

Comment: What do you mean by "preload feature"?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr from `node --help`: `-r, --require         module to preload (option can be repeated)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var package = require('./package.json');

for (var i in package) {
      if (typeof package[i] === 'object' && package[i].hasOwnProperty("name"))
          console.log(package[i].name)
}
```