# Is there a way to get version from package.json in Meteor code?

Tags: meteor

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22339262/276311) explains how to read the package.json "version" from a `npm start`ed application. Is there an `env` variable in Meteor (1.3+) with this info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is not npm_package_version environment value in process object.

But you get the value of version using following code :

```
var pjson = require('/package.json'); 
console.log(pjson.version); // This will print the version
```

Comment: Good one, Pankaj. Maybe it'd be a good idea to wrap it in a server method to avoid sharing restricted info to the client.