# display the current npm version of my NodeJs app

Tags: reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6, webpack

I just want to display the version value of my package.json file within the footer of my app, but have no idea how to do that. I've read you could access those properties with process env object. Is it correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get version from package.json in nodejs code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running your app within **NodeJs**, you can access it by doing

```
process.env.npm_package_version
```

With **ES6**, you can also do

```
import {version} from './package.json';
```

Answer (score 1):

### The correct answers will be here in example:

1. Answer (this code include `package.json` file and get version)

   `const { version } = require('./package.json');`

---

2. Answer

   `const version = process.env.npm_package_version`

---

Please don't use `JSON.parse`, `fs.readFile`, `fs.readFileSync` and don't use another `npm modules` it's not necessary for this question.