# How to get the version from the package.json in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, versioning

I have found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9153571/2777965).

I have tried to get the version from the package.json using:

```
import { version } from './package.json';
```

but it results in:

```
package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts',
'.tsx', '.d.ts'.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are are in a commonJS environment, why not simply use

```
const pj = require('./package.json')
console.log(pj.version)
```

**EDIT**

Since you seem to be using webpack, just add the appropriate loader

```
   module: {
    loaders: [
        ...
        {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
        ....
```

which obviously you need to install using `npm install`

Comment: Now it returns: `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`. Perhaps it could be caused by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33469929/2777965)?

Comment: `"json-loader": "0.5.4"` had to be added to the package.json, then `npm install` had to be run indeed and now the version is shown. Thank you +1

Comment: This works, but it also includes you whole package.json into your compiled javascript module and exposes it to the public who use your site. You're adding unnecessary code and exposing your site to potential vulnerabilities by cataloging everything you use and whatever settings you've put in package.json

Comment: @Daniel San 1/ this is an answer to a specific question, not a security thesis. If you want to read something, you need access to it. 2/ not all apps are 'sites' and no, this is not a 'total security hole'

Comment: I expect answers not only to be technically correct but have common sense and good practices. Imagine a novice doing what is stated here. It will be a mess

Comment: @Daniel San. Sure. I humbly only answer questions I am asked, I am not on an evangelizing mission for newbies. But go ahead. Since you "know", answer the question too. Come up with a professional and detailed reason why this a "security hole" and a better approach. Blanket statement like yours without argumentation are of no help

Comment: See my answer for a less scary version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67701490/106623

Answer (score 59):

The way I like to do this without requiring webpack or any other dependencies is to add a `prebuild` script to `package.json` that writes the version to a TypeScript source file that can be imported elsewhere.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "node -p \"'export const LIB_VERSION = ' + JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version) + ';'\" > src/version.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
  }
```

This runs node.js with the `-p/--print` flag which evaluates the following code:

`'export const LIB_VERSION = ' + JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version) + ';'`

and redirects the output to `src/version.ts`

This results in `src/version.ts` containing:

`export const LIB_VERSION = "1.0.0";`

You can then simply import and use this from other files:

`import { LIB_VERSION } from './version';`

You probably want to exclude `src/version.ts` from source control so its changes don't litter your change history!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is by far the best Typescript way for today

Comment: Very excellent. I only recommend that you put this same script on `preinstall` instead of `prebuild`, that way it runs always even if you have multiple build scripts. Otherwise you have to add the `npm run prebuild &&` before each build script

Comment: What if you change the version and don't install again? Many CI scripts will update the version after install and before build. Put it wherever makes sense for you but for the vast majority it'll be prebuild

Comment: @Tim that is a fair assessment. For some that may work perfectly. Thanks for putting this script together!

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods, but the one I found most useful was using ng-node-environment package. This generates a file `./src/environments/base.ts` that you can directly reference in your typescript imports. It contains a const object called `sharedEnvironment`. Your import line looks like this: `import sharedEnvironment from './base'`;

When you execute the command, it looks for all environment variables beginning with 'NG_' and adds them as properties to `sharedEnvironment`.

So, I created a `package.json` script that sets the variable and executes the ng-node-environment. For compatibility, I used cross-env to make it platform agnostic (works on windows and *nix)

Here's my package.json script: -

```
"scripts": {
    "version": "cross-env-shell NG_APPVERSION=$npm_package_version node ./node_modules/ng-node-environment/index.js",
    "another" : "echo hello world"
}
```

Then run: `npm run version` to extract the version and put it in `./src/environments/base.ts`

I can now access property `appversion` and use it in my `environment.ts`.

**Note**: If I had called the variable `NG_APP_Version` the property name would be camel cased to `appVersion`

```
import sharedEnvironment from './base';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  logLevel: LogLevel.Error,
  version : sharedEnvironment.appversion,
};
```

Of course, this way I can add other values from `package.json` by setting other variables before execution of `ng-node-environment`, or can add more properties in advance by creating variables called `NG_<Something>` e.g: `NG_GitBranch`, `NG_ComputerName`, `NG_CliVersion` etc

When developing in Angular and to ensure it's in sync all the time, I start development with a start script: -

```
"scripts": {
    "version": "cross-env-shell NG_APPVERSION=$npm_package_version node ./node_modules/ng-node-environment/index.js",
    "start": "npm run version && ng serve"
}
```

So I type: `npm start` and it syncs the version number, builds and launches

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do this, very similar to [Tim's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67701490).

I needed some additional fields, like the name and the description, which would be tedious to assemble with `node -p`.

If you're up for a dependency, you can gain some concision and flexibility:

Add [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to your project:

```bash
npm install node-jq -D
```

Then in your `package.json`, you can add a one-liner to pull whichever fields you want:

```json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "prebuild": "jq '{version, name, description}' package.json > ./src/pkgInfo.json",
    ...
  }
```

Then elsewhere in your project, you can access your curated fields:

```
import pkgInfo from './pkgInfo.json' assert { type: 'json' };

console.log(`I am ${pkgInfo.name} v${pkgInfo.version}, some say I ${pkgInfo.description}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a bits from @Tim made a script and also used it in `preinstall` like @TetraDev suggested. Hope if helps!

```js
import {
  writeFile
} from 'fs';
import {
  join
} from 'path';

// add respective keys you'd like
const keys = ['example', 'key'];
const destination = '/path/of/destination'

import (join(process.cwd(), 'package.json'), {
  assert: {
    type: 'json'
  }
})
.then((module) => {
    const packageJson = module.default;
    const filteredPkg = keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
      if (packageJson[key]) obj[key] = packageJson[key];
      return obj;
    }, {});

    const exportString = `export const packageVersions = ${JSON.stringify(filteredPkg, null, 2)};\n`;

    const outputPath = join(process.cwd(), destination);

    writeFile(outputPath, exportString, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error writing to file:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('File has been saved:', outputPath);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error('Error loading package.json:', error));
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to avoid including the whole package.json file, I usually create a template named `buildData.json` and put it in a `templates` folder.  I give it the following contents.

```json
{
    "version": [<%= options.version %>]
}
```

Then in `nuxt.config.js`, add the template to the build section:

```js
  build: {
    templates: [
      {
        src: "./templates/buildData.json",
        dst: "../buildData.json",
        options: {
          version: require("./package.json").version
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This will generate a `buildData.json` file that will contain **only** the version number.  The full `package.json` file is read only during build time and is not included the files sent to the browser.

Finally, add this code wherever you need the version number:

```js
const version = require("@/buildData.json").version;
```

Make sure the file you give to the `require` statement is the generated `buildData.json` and not the one in the `templates` folder.