# Error: Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as 'version')

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have an ejected create-react-app project. I am getting this error after updating it to webpack 5. It was working fine with webpack v4.41.5

OS: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
node: v10.23.0

> Error: Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as
> 'version') from default-exporting module (only default export is
> available soon).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes. The error was because of the following line in the code. `const packageJson = require('../package.json')`.

Comment: Solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298948/how-to-securely-import-version-from-package-json-while-respecting-error-should/70333147#70333147

Comment: Here's another option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123631/how-to-get-the-version-from-the-package-json-in-typescript

Comment: @karel I am writing this comment in response to your edit. The webpack config is not useful to the question. The only thing that matters is the upgrade to webpack 5 form webpack 4.

Comment: I removed the webpack config.

Comment: I see a lot of users doing the complete import and then destructuring it later. The question still remains though why `import {abc} from "some.json"` warns me when  `abc` attribute exists in json?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Change the following

```
import { version } from '../../package.json';
```

to something like

```
import packageInfo from '../../package.json';
```

And then change your access from something like

```
version,
```

or

```
version: version,
```

to

```
version: packageInfo.version,
```

As noted in the comments, there may be cases where you do not want to expose your entire `package.json` file in the client code.

Comment: But doesn't this pose a security risk and expose the entire package.json to the client?

Comment: That question seems unrelated to the question above. My answer simply addresses the question, not whether it is a good practice or secure in all contexts. If you have private/secret contents in your `package.json` and don't want them to ever be available in your JS code, then don't do this. How to do this in a more secure way should be covered in a separate question.

Comment: import * as packageInfo from '../../package.json';
version: packageInfo.version,

Comment: @Splaktar even without secrets in the `package.json` I find this **extremely unsecure**. Most devs and maintainers, even with experience, will not treat the `package.json` as something in the public domain. And with an implementation like that 'hidden' in the codebase really painful shots in the foot lie ahead. Especially so since this error now comes up for Angular 12 which is client-side technology. So a **clearly visible HEADS-UP** would be fitting imho.

Comment: Agree with @JeyDWork, this solution should be flagged as potential security risk. If your `package.json` doesn't contain confidential data now, who will guarantee that other developers won't put it there years later, without knowing that it is exposed to production? And even without any secrets, normally, a business doesn't want to expose information about its `dependencies` and `devDependencies` from the `package.json` to everybody - it makes it easier to find vulnerabilities and penetrate the application.

Comment: Follow-up question on how to do this securely here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298948/how-to-securely-import-version-from-package-json-while-respecting-error-should

Comment: This does not fix the issue, you will now get this Warning instead.

`Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as 'packageJson') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)`

Comment: Update the import statement as `import packageInfo from '../../package.json';` @Breakpoint25

Comment: how to handle if need to import multiple `packageinfo` from different packages?

Comment: Guys I think Answer from Nihar H Rupareliya might be the best option for this. Could you check if there could be anything wrong with it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689192/4312730

Answer (score 40):

You should also add
`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,`
to the compileroptions in the tsconfig.json

Comment: tried on Angular v12 (after upgrading from v9). Did not work in my case. tried to add both to `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`

Comment: @NuryagdyMustapayev this worked for me: `import * as packageInfo from '../../package.json';` and rename the variable instead of accesing `version` directly `someName = packageInfo`

Comment: maybe you also have to add "resolveJsonModule": true, "esModuleInterop": true to your tsconfig.json to be able to apply default import for json

Comment: may be worth to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript

Answer (score 33):

I solved my issue with the following:

```ts
    import packageInfo from './package.json';
    
    
    version = packageInfo.version;
```

Comment: This syntax is the correct syntax to use

Comment: This together with `"resolveJsonModule": true, "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

Comment: Why does this doesn't expose something in comparison to `{ key }` import?

Answer (score 16):

How about `const appVersion = require('./package.json').version;` ?

Using this we are not actually shipping the whole package.json but just bringing in the version from it.

Comment: I imported JSON files in the unit testing codes in my Angular project. I started getting this error after upgrading the Angular version to v12. In my test code, I already was importing in the correct way as described in the accepted answer, but I was getting this error. Changing to `require` is solved for me. thanks.

Comment: Best answer, 1 line of code.

Answer (score 9):

With latest version of `create react app`, following syntax works:

```
import rData from './registration-form.json';
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I have solved the issue (the rest of the answers didn't work for me). Solution found from here https://www.angularfix.com/2021/10/error-should-not-import-named-export.html

### Step 1

add the following to your `ts.config` file

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

(add them at the end of your "compileroptions" block)

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    // 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
```

### Step 2

Import the file you want using the following syntax. Of course change the name of the file to your file name.

```
import {default as data} from '../../package.json';
```

### Step 3

You can now access your variables via this syntax

```
data.variable_name
```

This is basically what my file looks like, it compiles successfully

```
import {default as authInfo} from '../../auth_config.json';

export const environment = {
  // 
  domain: authInfo.domain,
  clientId: authInfo.clientId
};
```

Comment: This solution helped me, and it's precisely what I needed because I'm in the middle of authentication configuration too :)

Answer (score 4):

**For Angular 12 +,
Follow this steps:**

**Step 1:**
We need to use the `require` node function in our environment files, so we have to add node types to the compiler options. Open tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json files (usually they are located under the ‘src’ folder), add “node” under compilerOptions -> types

```
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  }
...
```

Note: Be sure to have included ‘@type/node’ as a dependency in your ‘package.json’ file.

**Step 2:**
Now open environment.ts (‘src\environments\environment.ts’) and create a property for holding the application version in environment variable as follows ( in our case this will be `appVersion`) :

```
export const environment = {
  appVersion: require('../../package.json').version + '-dev',
  production: false
};
```

Be aware, the path to package.json must be calculated from the environment file’s location.

The require(‘../../package.json’).version will load the version number from the package.json file and + ‘-dev’ will add the ‘-dev’ suffix to it. The suffix isn’t a must, but this way you can identify witch environment file is used for running your application

Following the same approach we have to edit the production environment file as well. In the end the environment.prod.ts will look like this:

```
export const environment = {
    appVersion: require('../../package.json').version,
    production: true
};
```

**Step 3:**
Add version number to a component and show it in the application. For example:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h3>v{{currentApplicationVersion}}</h3>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Demo application for version numbering';
    currentApplicationVersion = environment.appVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error then I realize that the issue was because I used

`import {logo} from '../assets/logo.png';`

Instead of

`import logo from '../assets/logo.png';`

The curly braces are only used for import when export is named. For a default export (a file which isn't being exported from another) we do not use { } when we import

Answer (score 0):

Just for further reference this does not happen with just the package.json
I had the same problem with packages from the @atlaskit after an update to webpack v5 and found good explanation and fix [there](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/error-should-not-import-the-named-export-in-editor-core/54982/5):

> You can import JSON files directly into Javascript files. This is supported by node and by Webpack. In older versions of Webpack you could import either the default export which represents the whole JSON blob or a named export for each top level property in the JSON file.

> As of Webpack 5 the named export is deprecated which mirrors the behaviour of node.

To work around use in webpack config:

```
ignoreWarnings: [
/only default export is available soon/,
],
```

Comment: Ok as a temporary solution, but not good in long term because Webpack threatens to remove the named export support.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late but I am adding it because it will help some others.
first you have to import the file like import bglogo from "../data/data.json"
then create a variable const logo=bglogo.logo;
the use it as logo

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error and i fixed it by deleting the curly braces {} when importing Logo.png photo ..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked with Angular 16.
Here is what did work for me.

1. ```
   "compilerOptions": {
     // 
     "resolveJsonModule": true,
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
   },
   ```
2. ```
   import * as packageInfo from '../../package.json';
   ```

   > **Note:** If you try to reference `packageInfo.version` (or any other attribute) you get "Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as 'packageInfo')"
3. Use the component constructor

   ```
   const zx = JSON.stringify(packageInfo);
   const zxj = JSON.parse(zx);
   console.log(zxj.version);

   this.version = zxj.version;
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should only change the following import:

```
import { version } from '../../package.json';
```

with the following import:

```
import version from '../../package.json';
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What you are suggesting can be confusing because the imported object will contain the complete json object from the package.json file and not just the version.

I think a better alternative would be:

`import packagejson from '../../package.json';`
`const {version} = packageJson;`