# How to fix angular yelling Should not import the named export... from JSON?

Tags: json, angular

I've seen this question pop up in multiple places, so sorry if this seems to be a copy. In angular I'm importing a JSON like
`import {domain, clientId} from '../../auth_config.json';`

This was working until today, and after doing a npm install, it has stopped. I already have this in my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "tslib": [
        "path/to/node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"
      ]
```

I also saw others say to try importing as
`import * as auth from'../../auth_config.json';`
and using `auth.domain` instead of `domain`. However Angular still throws the same error.  I've also tried  `import {domain as d, clientId as c} from '../../auth_config.json';` with no such luck.

My Enviroment that throws the error:

```
import {domain, clientId} from '../../auth_config.json';
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  auth: {
    domain,
    clientId,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin
  }
};
```

The exact error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/environments/environment.ts 19:8-14

Should not import the named export 'domain' (imported as 'domain') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)


ERROR in ./src/environments/environment.ts 20:8-16

Should not import the named export 'clientId' (imported as 'clientId') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
```

Using

```
import * as auth from '../../auth_config.json';
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  auth: {
    domain: auth.domain,
    clientId: auth.clientId,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin
  }
};
```

Gives this result:

```
ERROR in ./src/environments/environment.ts 22:16-27

Should not import the named export 'domain' (imported as 'auth') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)


ERROR in ./src/environments/environment.ts 23:18-31

Should not import the named export 'clientId' (imported as 'auth') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
```

And Auth_config.json:

```
{
  "domain": "dev-beazcaxy.us.auth0.com",
  "clientId": "6Iewy037OUNolNG9Q7o...",
  "audience": "{API_IDENTIFIER}",
  "apiUri": "http://localhost:3001",
  "appUri": "http://localhost:4200",
  "errorPath": "/error"
}
```

The only thing that I found that I did not try was [How to securely import version from package.json while respecting Error: Should not import the named export 'version'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298948/how-to-securely-import-version-from-package-json-while-respecting-error-should), however, that seems to be for react. IDK if that is similar to how to do it in Angular or not.

Comment: `import * as auth from'../../auth_config.json';` or `import auth from'../../auth_config.json` are correct. If it throws an error, I doubt it is the same error. If it doesn't work, please show what your code looks like when you try it, and what error you are getting.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I added what happens when I use * as auth. Does that help?

Comment: try `import { default as auth } from '../../auth_config.json';` Could you also include what version of angular you're using?

Comment: I'm using Angular: 13.3.2, as well as Angular CLI: 13.3.2
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.0. 
Weird, that import does work. If you can put that as an answer, I'll close this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```js
import { default as auth } from '../../auth_config.json';
```

or just

```js
import auth from '../../auth_config.json';
```

provided you have these two flags in `tsconfig.json`

```js
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

---

Interestingly, this import works

```js
import * as auth from '../../auth_config.json';
```

Until you try to index into a property

```js
console.log(auth.domain);
```

this is what throws the error.
It seems to be the way that the typescript compiler converts the json to a module, if we do

```js
console.log(auth);
```

we see

```json
Object { domain: Getter, clientId: Getter, audience: Getter, apiUri: Getter, appUri: Getter, errorPath: Getter, default: Getter, … }
​
__esModule: true
​
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
​
<get apiUri()>: function key()​
<get appUri()>: function key()​
<get audience()>: function key()​
<get clientId()>: function key()​
<get default()>: function default()​
<get domain()>: function key()​
<get errorPath()>: function key()
```

notice the `default` getter. This explains the error message, because there is a default export, the compiler does not want us to call any other functions. This also explains the name of `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`.

We could access the object like this

```js
console.log((auth as any).default.domain);
```

and that's essentially what the above syntax is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { default as auth } from '../../auth_config.json';
```

this was what worked for me