# Get version number from package.json in React Redux (create-react-app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux, create-react-app

**OP EDIT: If anyone else comes across this: the app was created using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), which limits importing to within the src folder. However if you [upgrade react-scripts to v1.0.11](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2466) it does let you access package.json.**

I'm trying to get the version number from package.json in my app.

I've already tried [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code), but none of them have worked as I can't access package.json from outside the src folder (might be due to React, I'm new to this). Moving package.json into src then means I can't run `npm install`, `npm version minor`, and `npm run build` from my root folder. I've tried using `process.env.npm_package_version` but that results in undefined.

I'm using Jenkins, and I haven't set it up to push the commits up yet, but the only idea I have is to get the version from the tags in GitLab, but I have no idea how to do that, and it would add unnecessary dependency to the repo, so I would really like to find an alternative.

EDIT: 
My file structure is like:

```
--> RootAppFolder
    |--> build
    |--> node_modules
    |--> public
    |--> src
         |--> Components
              |--> Root.js
    |
    |--> package.json
```

So to access package.json from Root.js I have to do `import packageJson from './../../package.json'` and then I get the following error:

> ./src/components/Root.js
>
> Module not found: You attempted to import
>   ./../../package.json which falls outside of the project src/
>   directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can
>   either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's
>   node_modules/.

Comment: Did you tried the es6 version also ?

Comment: "I can't access package.json from outside the src folder" -- can you explain on this? If `package.json` can be accessed, the version number can be easily retrieved.

Comment: @kenfire what do you mean? I'm not very familiar with ES6.

Comment: @shaochuancs I have edited to explain. Moving package.json into the src folder works to get the version, but then I can't run any of the npm commands to actually build and run the app.

Comment: @user3255240 In ES6 the syntax is different for imports: `import {version} from './package.json'; ` instead of `var data = require('./package.json');`

Comment: @kenfire ah, thank you. Yes, I'm using the ES6 syntax, but it's still not working, due to package.json being outside the src folder.

Comment: @user3255240 Don't move package.json. It should be located in the project's root path.

Comment: @user3255240 are you using some build systems or other tools? If you use Node.js alone, there is no restrict on "Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported".

Comment: @shaochuancs yes, turns out the app was created using react-create-app which puts a restriction through webpack.

Comment: For Next.js v14 you can now do `import packageJson from "../package.json";` which returns an object containing the version attribute.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From your edit I would suggest to try:

```bash
import packageJson from '/package.json';
```

You could also try to create a symlink:

```bash
# From the project root.
cd src; ln -s ../package.json package.alias.json
```

List contents of src directory and you'll see the symlink.

```bash
ls
#=> package.alias.json -> ../package.json
```

Adding the `.alias` helps reduce the "magic" for others and your future self when looking at this. Plus, it'll help text editors keep them apart. You'll thank me later. Just make sure you update your JS code to import from `./package.alias.json` instead of `./package.json`.

Also, please take a look at this question:
[The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Comment: While the imports still didn't work, I didn't realise the app was created using create-react-app which is where the issue is coming from. So I guess the solution then, is to look into webpack and configure it myself and get rid of this limitation.

Comment: As the OP mentioned in an edit to their question, this is no longer necessary. Newer versions of `react-scripts` allows you to import from outside of `src`.

Comment: Adding package.json to your bundle is not a good idea. It would expose all your dependencies to potential attackers, plus it's a fairly large object and the data you need is only a handful of bytes.

Comment: @EricBurel does this apply when referring to RN packages as well? I already expose the package.json when publishing my package (and any other packages do this as well).

Comment: Probably yes, if you bundle it into the app then the user can access it. This isn't the craziest leak but still a leak

Comment: `import packageJson from '/package.json';` worked for me. For Typescript users, add `"resolveJsonModule": true,`

Comment: Who cares if someone decompiles the app and sees that it uses whatever library? Why is this a security concern? The only way to prevent people from decompiling your code is not to ship a binary in the first place.

Comment: How is `package.json` a "fairly large object", too large to import? It's a few lines of JSON.

Comment: This solution doens't work when you make of prod build of your react app. In my case (not a really experienced react developer, so correct me if I am wrong) I didn't have a package.json in my build folder, after building.

Answer (score 332):

Solving this without importing and exposing `package.json` to the `create-react-app`

**Requires: [version 1.1.0+](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3387) of create-react-app**

**`.env`**

```
REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
REACT_APP_NAME=$npm_package_name
```

**`index.js`**

```
console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_NAME} ${process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION}`)
```

***Note:*** the version (and many other [npm config params](https://gist.github.com/moos/4635bda5b04dc8113d8ea7ee974cabc2)) can be accessed

***Note 2:*** changes to the `.env` file will be picked only after you [restart the development server](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Comment: I had to create `.env` (as plain text file) in repository root to make it work. like it

Comment: @JoeMaffei This is a fine solution, but referencing the `package.json` file with `import { name, version } from "../package.json";` is less cryptic and doesn't require creating an `.env` file.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 But it's not gonna work with Create React App as it doesn't allow to reference outside of `src/`.

Comment: Don't forget to `npm start` again after changing `.env`

Comment: Just found that `NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version` in an .env file works for next.js (I'm using 9.5.3) also, although I don't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored

Comment: How would this work for JSON env files like env-cmdrc? It has trouble parsing

Comment: What if we use yarn? Will it also work then?

Comment: REACT_APP_HOMEPAGE doesn't work for this case :(

Comment: On Windows in .env file use REACT_APP_VERSION=${npm_package_version} (development). In production, it seems to work fine REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version

Answer (score 66):

Try this.

```
// in package.json
"version": "1.0.0"

// in index.js
import packageJson from '../package.json';
console.log(packageJson.version); // "1.0.0"
```

Comment: Using Expo and this worked like a charm for me. I called mine appJson, so it was `console.log(appJson.expo.version);`. Thanks!

Comment: This will import whole package.json in your bundle

Comment: @inferus-vv you can `import { version } from '../package.json';`

Comment: insecure! you don't want to expose your package.json to users and hackers

Comment: @Alina_Lapina does this apply when talking about RN packages as well? Already when publishing my package I expose the package.json (and any other packages do this as well)

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru, yes it does. Take a look https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env
React lib has a mechanism for this. Define REACT_APP_<SOMETHING> environment variables to expose selected setup data, but not the setup itself.

Comment: What about just importing the `version` like `import { version } from '../package.json';`. Does that avoid the security risk and bundle size concerns?

Answer (score 40):

I don't think getting version by 'import' or 'require' package is correct.
You can add a script in you package.json

```
"start": "REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-app-script start",
```

You can get it by "process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION" in any js files.

It also works in build scripts, like this:

```
"build": "REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-app-script build",
```

Answer (score 28):

#### import package.json

Generally speaking, **importing `package.json` is not good**. Reasons: security & bundle size concerns

Yes, latest webpack (default config) + ES6 `import` does tree-shaking (i.e. only includes the `"version"` value instead of the whole `package.json`) for both `import packageJson from '../package.json'` and `import { version } from '../package.json'`. But it is not guaranteed if you use CommonJS (`require()`), or have altered your webpack config, or use another bundler/transpiler. It's weird to rely on bundler's tree-shaking to hide your sensitive data. If you insist on importing `package.json` but do not want the whole `package.json` exposed, you may want to add some post-build checks to ensure other values in `package.json` are removed.

However the security concern here remains theoretical for open source projects whose `package.json` is public after all. If both security and bundle size are not problems, or, the non-guaranteed tree-shaking is good enough for you, then go ahead)

#### .env

The `.env` method, if it works, then it's good, but if you don't use `create-react-app`, you might need to install `dotenv` and do some additional configurations. There's also one **small concern: it is not recommended to commit the `.env` file ([here](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file) and [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/218a941be92679ce67d0484547e3e142b2f5f6f0/Node.gitignore#L72)), but if you do the `.env` method, it looks like you will have to commit the file** as it likely becomes essential for your program to work.

#### Best practice (arguably)

*(this is not primarily for `create-react-app`, but you still can either use [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) or [eject cra](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) in order to configure `webpack` in cra)*

If you use `webpack`, then with [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/):

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.VERSION': JSON.stringify(
      process.env.npm_package_version,
    ),
  }),
]
```

You can now use `console.log(process.env.VERSION)` in your front-end program (development or production).

(You could simply use `VERSION` instead of `process.env.VERSION`, but it usually requires additional configuration to satisfy linters: add `globals: {VERSION: 'readonly'}` in `.eslintrc` ([doc](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals)); add `declare var VERSION: string;` in `.d.ts` file for TypeScript)

Although it's "**npm**_package_version", it works with `yarn` too. Here's [a list of npm's exposed environment variables](https://gist.github.com/moos/4635bda5b04dc8113d8ea7ee974cabc2).

Other bundlers may have similar plugins, for example, [@rollup/plugin-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace).

Comment: That's a verbose and very helpful answer, thank you! :)
Let's say I have bundled my package.json with my application, what would be the security concerns?

Comment: @NikitaMalyschkin if you have already included the whole package.json in your production code, then there would be no additional concern when you import it for the version number. But you might want to revise the decision to include the whole package.json in the first place.

Comment: What is this "sensitive information" that everyone is including in their `package.json`? Every `package.json` that I've ever seen is just a boring list of dependencies and version numbers. Who cares if someone sees it by decompiling the app? I don't see the security concern with just importing `package.json`. No one has explained what this supposed security concern is, everyone is just stating that it exists.

Comment: @AndrewKoster if it's an open source project, then there's no such concern. If it's private, then dependency list and other configurations may reveal things the project's owner does not want to be publicly known. For example if a vulnerability of a dependency is found, it's easier for hackers to launch some so-called 0-day attacks.

Comment: @AndrewKoster It's also possible for hackers to find a way to change a known upstream dependency in order to attack the downstream dependencies and apps. E.g. you know a big big website is using library A, you "social engineer" library A's maintainer and get access and add a bitcoin miner in the code, then all the big big website's viewers will mine Bitcoin for you... It may not be exactly like what I said but it actually happened before, you can Google it

Comment: @AndrewKoster It's not that front-end does not need to worry about security, there are SQL injection and cross-site-related stuff to worry about. It's true that if your front and back are well separated and backend API endpoints are well writen, fewer security problems front-end will need to handle, but such problems do exist. Futhermore, package.json may sometimes reveal backend dependencies and config if a (incompetent) dev uses node in backend and uses a same package.json or at least put some back dependencies & configs in the package.json...

Answer (score 1):

I have approached this by writing a .json file with any needed information during a pre-build step and then importing that into my code. This should work for any kind of web app and not just React apps.

writeBuildInfo.js:

```js
const buildInfo = {
    version: process.env.npm_package_version,
    buildDate: new Date().getTime(),
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(buildInfo));
```

package.json script run during pre-build:

```
"get-build-info": "node builds/writeBuildInfo.js > src/buildInfo.json",
```

Import:

```js
import buildInfo from './buildInfo';
```

I have been using this for several years and it has worked quite well.

Of course, make sure to list this buildInfo.json file in your .gitignore, since it is essentially a build output.

Answer (score -3):

Open your package.json file and change this line

**Problem Is:**

> // in package.json
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "dev": "REACT_APP_VERSION=local REACT_APP_VERSION_NUMBER=$npm_package_version react-scripts start",
> ...
> }
> ```

Solution is

> // in package.json
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "dev": "react-scripts start",
> ...
> }
> ```