# Abstracting a version number from a package.json file to be displayed to users in a web app

Tags: reactjs, version, package.json

I have a task of adding a version number to the UI in a react web app. Since my package.json file does contain a version number is it possible to use that value as a variable in my app? Ive tried importing the package.json but this does not work. Im not sure how I should approach this in a web app any advice would be helpful.
This is the beginning of my package.json where the version number lives:

```
{
  "name": "emr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Reliant EMR",
  "main": "index.js",
...
```

Ive tried importing the package.json like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Version } from "../../../package.json"
```

I've started this by only trying to get the value out of the Version

```
console.log(Version.version)
```

Comment: Please give us code

Comment: You want to see my package.json?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get version number from package.json in React Redux (create-react-app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978230/get-version-number-from-package-json-in-react-redux-create-react-app)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code?rq=1

Comment: What is returned is `undefined` I was expecting it return 1.0.0

Comment: `import { Version }` should be `version`, no?

Comment: Thank you it was just the { }  that was causing the undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `{}` in this case. `Version` is not exported. Just remove the brackets and use

```
import Version from "../../../package.json";
```

Comment: This raises an error: Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../../package.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory