# How can I get cached package.json data in my browser in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json

I have a React app and I'd like to get the version number that the browser has cached and is showing to the user. How can I do this? Thanks.

I have the following in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "arkreskin",
  **"version": "0.2.04.1",**
  "private": true,
}
```

Comment: [You need an .ENV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978230/get-version-number-from-package-json-in-react-redux-create-react-app).

Comment: I see in that link how you can get the version, but what about the version which is cached and currently running in the browser?