# ReactJS - $npm_package_version param not working on build version

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app

I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978230/get-version-number-from-package-json-in-react-redux-create-react-app) but it didn't work for me.

My React app(18.2.0v) was initialized with CRA(5.0.1v).
My *dotenv* version is 16.0.3.

On development version I get *package.json* file version successfully, but on build version I can't get it.

My `.env.staging` file:

```
NODE_ENV=development
REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
```

My `package.json` scripts:

```
{
  ...
  "version": "0.1.0",
  ...      
  "scripts":
    {
      ...
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      ...
      "build:staging": "npm run clean && env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
      ...
    }
...
}
```

My Login.tsx display version this way:

```
...
const { REACT_APP_VERSION } = process.env;
...
return (
...
<h1>V{REACT_APP_VERSION}</h1>
...
)
...
```

[Dev mode display print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n0px.png)

[Build mode display print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skke8.png)

I have an `.env.development` with the same content as the current `.env.staging` quoted above that will be used for another build version.

Have someone any idea how to solve this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this when I installed *dotenv-cli* and changed package.json *build:staging* script to `"npm run clean && dotenv -e .env.staging react-scripts build"`