# Get the version number of an installed Node package without loading it?

Tags: node.js, npm, version

It is possible [to get the version of the current package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code) via

```js
const { version } = require('./package.json')
```

but how can I get the version number of an arbitrary, installed package without loading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with `require.resolve`:

```js
const path = require('path')

// get version number without requiring the module
function packageVersion(moduleName) {
  const dir = path.dirname(require.resolve(moduleName))
  return require(path.join(dir, 'package.json')).version
}
```