# TypeScript OutDir contains package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

I'm trying to build my simple npm package, and all is well. However when I'm trying to build it it goes a bit wrong.

I get the following:

```
 - dist
   - package.json
   - src
      - index.js
      - index.d.ts
      - ...
```

But this is not what I expected to get, I'm pretty sure I've done this before and gotten, the following:

```
 - dist
   - index.js
   - index.d.ts
   - ...
```

This is what I want to end up with, but so far nothing has worked.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist"]
}
```

I haven't been able to find a reason for it to include the `package.json` or the `src` path. I'm using `typescript@3.6.4`.

Comment: @Bauke I did, and that seems to have been the hidden problem. Used it to include a version number. If you know of a way that I can include it but bundle it, that would be a even better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you importing your `package.json` anywhere in your code? If you are, [it's getting copied because of `resolveJsonModule`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32268).

If you want to read JSON files without them being copied over, you can do a `readFile` and `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Will this work for browser packages? I haven't tried it yet, but seems to me like that would be a problem.

Comment: Ah, no. The `readFile` approach won't work for browsers. If you want to include that there I'd suggest just sticking with either having a variable in your code for the version or [using `require` or something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855054/12251171).