# How to do app versioning in create react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, version, versioning, build-numbers

I need to display **version** of my react app in the footer in **x.y.z** format.

I need this version to increment every time I deploy the app by being provided a choice if I want to increment **x** or **y** or **z**.

How do I achieve this? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To bump the version of your app you can use [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-version).

For example:

```
npm version minor
```

Comment: that's part of the solution but doesn't explain how to get it displayed

Answer (score 12):

Once you have a way to bump the version in package.json (e.g. `npm version`, as suggested by @bertrand-p), you can then assign the version to an environment variable.  For example, in `.env` you can set:

```
REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
```

Then you can access the variable from within your app via `process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION`.

See also: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2466#issuecomment-357490359

Comment: Thanks, this is working with `yarn` too. Is it okay to use `REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version` with `yarn`?

Comment: @SankaSanjeewa Yes, that should work

Comment: Do you know if I could link that to git's branch hash (git rev-parse HEAD)?

Comment: @Chrysanthemums I would assume you could override it with an arbitrary value from the shell e.g. `REACT_APP_VERSION=$(git rev-parse HEAD) npm run build`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the answers from @Bertrand P or @VulfCompressor tell the complete picture. I used genversion https://www.npmjs.com/package/genversion. The steps I did were:

1. `npm install genversion --save-dev`
2. Modify the build script in `package.json` to `genversion --es6 src/autobuild_version.js && react-scripts build` (I couldn't figure out a way to import the generated module from the `lib` directory as suggested in the genversion documentation so I had to put it in the `src` directory instead)
3. In the React app, `import { version }  from './autobuild_version'` and use as appropriate
4. Add `src/autobuild_version.js` to `.gitignore` (other source code control tools are available)
5. `npm run build`

Comment: have to give version whole app, then should I add it in index.js file or anything else

Comment: genversion creates a separate file containing just the version number. you can import it wherever you like

Comment: we can import from .env file also why should I use this package :-|

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm commands below in different conditions mentioned below and the commands will effect the version number in package.json in your react project.
You can access that version by installing dotenv by `npm i dotenv` or`yarn add dotenv` and use the .env file in your root folder and access the version number in the whole app with `REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version`. You can find more commands at [npm version documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-version) page. commands below will add to version numbers like this: `"version":"{major}.{minor}.{patch}"`

If its a major change(bug fixing) in your app use:

```
npm version major
```

If its a minor change(bug fixing) in your app use:

```
npm version minor
```

And if it's just a patch upgrade such as changing some styles use:

```
npm version patch
```

You can use versioning for many purposes and one of them is for making sure client's cache will be renew and they would have the updated content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grunt-bump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bump) to handle your app versioning. As for displaying your app version, refer to [Is there a way to get version from package.json in nodejs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code).

Comment: create react app isn't nodejs code - it's client-side javascript code and the accepted answer to that question is dangerous to do in the client.