# How to refer my package.json from /dist/app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dev

For my web application, when I try to import a version tag from package.json to app.js (/src/app.js), which is one level up to app.js, the local run works fine. But when I try to run from development by generating a dist folder, the code does not work even though both src and dist folder are at same level and should be able to access package.json.

When I deploy to development, I get error as follows:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

Can someone pls help me with this?

Comment: Please show how you try to get content of package.json file

Comment: how are you importing your package.json file in app.js?
You might be interested in referring this post >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855054/5210792

Comment: list the file tree of your project ,and explain how do you generating the dist folder.

Comment: @MarekSzkudelski Hi ... i use this ...import { version } from '../package.json';

Comment: @NicoNing: the path is use is as u see in the 1st answer..
dist/
src/
     app.js
package.json

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Node.js, which seems to be the case, use node native `path` module to resolve `package.json` path. Here is an example :

```
src/
  path/
    to/
      subdir/
        foo.js
index.js
package.json
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

**foo.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const packageJson = require(path.resolve('package.json'));

module.exports = {
  "packageVersion": packageJson.version
}
```

**index.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const packageJson = require(path.resolve('package.json'));
const foo = require('./src/path/to/subdir/foo');

console.log(packageJson.version);
console.log(foo.packageVersion);
```

When your run `node index`, you'll get the following output

```
1.0
1.0
```

The version from `package.json` is read from both `index.js` and `foo.js` using `path.resolve('package.json')`

Comment: Please consider to approve it then ^^