# Updating version number in multiple places before release

Tags: angular, npm, semantic-versioning

I have an Ionic app running on Angular 8 w/ npm and I have my app's version number in several places that need to be updated before each release.  I've seen `npm version` and I'm looking for something like that, that works in additional files as well.  Currently, my app's version number is referenced in:

```
main.yml
package.json
config.xml
app/pages/login/login.html
app/providers/sentry.service.ts
```

I didn't know if there would be a tool or simply a global search and replace but either would be okay by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible avoid duplicating the version number in the application. The angular app can read it from the package.json

```js
import pkg from './package.json';
console.log(pkg.version);
```

I would expect it would cover `app/pages/login/login.html` and `app/providers/sentry.service.ts`.

For the rest, I would consider [cordova hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/appdev/hooks/) `before_compile`. I believe the small script which would set the version would be the fast and reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it dynamically in your files like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code).

I personally use it like this:

```
import { version } from 'package.json';
```