# How check in typescript the modul version?

Tags: node.js

I want check the version of the mysql module in my typescript code.

I imagine code like this:

```
import mysql from "mysql"

if(mysql.version == "2.18.1"){
   ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to get the version directly from your package.json, for example with [`package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package). Something like this:

```
const package = require('package')(module);
console.log(package.dependencies.mysql);
```

You could also do `JSON.parse` and `fs.readFile`.

**Edit:**

Maybe you can add [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) and [`@types/npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/npm) to your dependencies and then:

```
import npm from 'npm';

npm.load((err, result) => {
  npm.commands.list([], (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Result:

```
[...]
├── dotenv@8.2.0
└── express@4.17.1
```

Comment: This is the version from package.json or?

Comment: Yes, it is. Though there might be better ways than this one.

Comment: The real version is listed at "npm list mysql". The version in package.json may be not the same! For checking I need the real version! The question is how npm read the version?

Comment: @Gerd I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let pjsonMysql: {version: string} = require('../node_modules/mysql/package.json');
console.log("version: " + pjsonMysql.version);

if(pjsonMysql.version == '2.18.1'){

}
```

It based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855054/1514029

The version is allways in package.json!

on mysql package for example

```
{
  "name": "mysql",
  "description": "A node.js driver for mysql. It is written in JavaScript, does not require compiling, and is 100% MIT licensed.",
  "version": "2.18.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Felix Geisendörfer <felix@debuggable.com> (http://debuggable.com/)",
  "contributors": [
...
]
}
```