# Accessing version in package.json in Angular NX monorepo

Tags: angular

I'm currently migrating a monolith Angular app into an Angular NX monorepo.
The footer component in the monolith accesses the 'version' in the package.json.
In the monorepo, the footer component lives in a lib, but I have no idea how to access the package.json file. Can someone please tell me how

Comment: Any of these should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can't access the files in the root folder of the monorepo from my lib

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. `Package.json` can't be accessed from a lib project, although it can be accessed from an app project. Taking this into consideration, you can create an `InjectionToken` which would hold the version.

Provide the token at the app level, and then inject it anywhere you need it.

It is generally a good practice to provide environment-related data at the app level.